# Getting an error for a non static method that cant be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

when i try to compile this it gives me an error for a non-static method begin(int) cannot be referenced from a static context. Any way this can be fixed?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import objectdraw.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Ricochet extends WindowController
{
    private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH=400;
    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT=600;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of box in pixels: ");
        int boxSize = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of crossings: ");
        int Crossings = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter pixel Speed: ");
        int pixelSpeed = scnr.nextInt();
        new Ricochet().startController(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        begin(boxSize);

    }
    private FilledRect sq1;
    public void begin(int boxSize)
    {
        sq1 = new FilledRect(1,1, boxSize, boxSize, canvas);
        sq1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

new Ricochet().startController(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
begin(boxSize);

Ricochet ricochet = new Ricochet().startController(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
ricochet.begin(boxSize);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
new Ricochet().startController(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
begin(boxSize);
```

Write:

```
 Ricochet ricochet = new Ricochet();
 ricochet.startController(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
 ricochet. begin(boxSize);
```

Your instance methods need to be called from an instance. Otherwise they need to be declared as `static`.

You should read this for more info:[Why non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/why-non-static-variable-cannot-be.html)

Comment: that is what i wrote in the original code :new Ricochet().startController(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
begin(boxSize);

Comment: ups :) Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call an instance method directly from a static context. so, compiler couldn't get to an instance method without giving it an instance reference from a static context. Not possible. so, Mark the method `begin` as static to make it to Class level. then, it becomes accessible from static context.

Solution is

```
public static void begin(int boxSize)
{
    sq1 = new FilledRect(1,1, boxSize, boxSize, canvas);
    sq1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

The other way is to invoke the method using the instance object

```
Ricochet instance = new Ricochet();
instance.startController(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
instance.begin(boxSize);
```

Hope you understand now clearly.

Comment: i cannot make begin as a static method otherwise i will get an error for sq1

Comment: Then you can make use of the second way. If you make `sq1` as also static, then also you will not get the error.